# DSolve is not able to find a solution in some points

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

When I use the below script to solve an equation and plot the solution, the plot shows some discontinuous lines. For example at point $x\approx0.25$ the solver cannot find the answer and the plot is discontinuous. How can I fix this problem?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

c = -0.8;
L = 1;
b = Pi/L;

{x1, x2} = {0, L};

eqn = f[x] == c Sin[2 f[x]] + b x + Pi/2;

f[x_] = f[x] /. 
   DSolve[{D[eqn, x], 
      f[0] == (f0 /. 
         Solve[(eqn /. x -> 0 /. f[0] -> f0), f0, Reals][[1]])}, 
     f[x], {x, x1, x2}][[1]] // FullSimplify

(*InverseFunction[-(1/2) Cos[2 #1]+#1&][(11 x)/10]*)

Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}]
```

Comment: Plot does not plot complex numbers.  With your code `f[0.1]=1.09728 -0.320829 I`.  You can choose to plot the real part with `Re[f[x]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

c = -4/5;
L = 1;
b = Pi/L;
{x1, x2} = {0, L};

eqn = f[x] == c Sin[2 f[x]] + b x + Pi/2;
```

The equation does not identify a unique initial condition

```
ic = f0 /. Solve[(eqn /. x -> 0 /. f[0] -> f0), f0, Reals]
```

[image]

Only one of the possible initial conditions leads to a solution

```
sol = Table[
   DSolve[{D[eqn, x], f[0] == ic[[n]]}, f[x], {x, x1, x2}] // 
    FullSimplify, {n, 1, 3}] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
f[x_] = f[x] /. sol[[2, 1]];
```

Not all values of `x` produce real results

```
f[0.1`15]

(* 1.0972751444995646 - 0.3208287706939249 I *)
```

Plotting,

```
Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2},
 PlotRange -> {0, 5.8},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 Exclusions -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried to find coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ myself so that $\sin(2f(x=0))=\sin(2f(x=L))$ and also $\cos(2f(x=0))=\cos(2f(x=L))$

Comment: Do not ask new questions in comments. Organize your thoughts and post a new question with all pertinent information. Then anyone who is interested will see the new question.